# Semantic UI > Accordion > Custom trigger element on nested accordion

Tags: semantic-ui

I want to have custom trigger element for top level accordion elements as well as for sub level. What will be the proper JS code for this structure?

```
<div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
        <span class="custom-trigger-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="title">
                <span class="custom-trigger-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html needs some tag correction.. but you can accomplish this with:

```
$('.ui.accordion').accordion().on('click', function(e) {


    console.log(e);

});
```

Now you have a reference to the clicked dom object and can get your "custom trigger" identifier(s).

If this is going to be a simple use case then I would recommend using the onclick="" html attribute or using an `<a>` tag.

See it in action: http://codepen.io/appsoa/details/XmYRyz/

**Markup, If using javascript to render the component:**

`<div class="ui styled accordion">
        <div class="active title">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1
        </div>
        <div class="active content">
            Welcome to level 1
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="active title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1A
                </div>
                <div class="active content">
                    <p>Level 1A Contents</p>
                    <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="title active">
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1A-A
                        </div>
                        <div class="content active">
                            Level 1A-A Contents
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1A-B
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            Level 1A-B Contents
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1B
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Level 1B Contents
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 1C
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Level 1C Contents
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Welcome to level 2</p>
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="active title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2A
                </div>
                <div class="active content">
                    <p>Level 2A Contents</p>
                    <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="title">
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2A-A
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            Level 2A-A Contents
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2A-B
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            Level 2A-B Contents
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2B
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Level 2B Contents
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i> Level 2C
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Level 2C Contents
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`